# Motorcycles: Way to maintain shiny chrome on exhaust outlets?

Tags: maintenance, motorcycle, exhaust

I have a motorcycle that has chromed exhaust pipes. I am worried that there will eventually be discolouration where the pipes join the engine, due to the heat. Is there a way to treat the pipes so that this does not occur? I want my exhaust to maintain a uniform chrome shine the entire length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to prevent exhaust pipes from bluing is to design them to prevent blueing in the first place, build them with double walls to keep the outsides from getting too hot. One thing you can do is remove the tinting after the fact: there are products out there, such as [Blue-Job](http://www.blue-job.com/) chrome polishes.